# Wordpress Yeloni Exit Popup Subscribe button appearence width incorrect

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

I'm using the Yeloni plugin for Wordpress to create an exit-intent pop-up.  All good with the exception of the "Subscribe" button which seems to have some bizarre red gradient button beneath it that I can't for the life of me style!

Here's the CSS I'm using:

```
                #autience-emailform-name-f2eHb {
                width:80%;
                }

                #autience-emailform-email-f2eHb {
                width:80%; }

                #autience-emailform-submit-f2eHb {
                width:80%; }


                #autience-close-f2eHb {
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                }

                .yel-heading-1{
                width: 50%;
                text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
                }

                .yel-subheading-1 {
                width: 100%;
                text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
                }

                yel-ep-submit-button-div {
                width: 80% !important ;
                }

                .yel-ep-form .yel-ep-element-button {
                 width: 80% !important;
                 margin: 0 auto;
                 float: none;
                 }
```

Basically, I want the Subscribe button to be the same as the two text fields (80%) but it's glitching.  Live preview is at http://www.donationboxes.org.uk - if you go as if you are going to close the page, it'll pop up.

Thanks! 
Scott

Answer (score 1):

```
.yel-ep-form .yel-ep-element-button {
 width: 82% !important;
 margin: 0 auto;
 float: none;
 }
```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately.  I have updated the main post with the new CSS, and you can see that whilst it is now definitely the right width in total, a certain percentage of the button still has that odd red gradient!  So odd.

Comment: DOPE! Got it       

`#autience-emailform-submit-f2eHb {
     width:100%; }`

Thanks for the help Arun!